# AngularJS Cookies are not working

Tags: angularjs, cookies

Code works, Cookie `myCookie` is accessible in the browser (checked with Firebug in Firefox) but in angular code, I am unable to get it. AngularJS version: 1.5.7

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$cookies', function ($scope, $http, $cookies) {
var dummy = {name: 'myuser', role: 'myrole'};
var authURL = 'http://mycustom.url';
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: authURL,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    transformRequest: function (obj) {
        var str = [];
        for (var p in obj)
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        return str.join("&");
    },
    data: dummy
})
    .then(function successCallback(response) {
        var cook = $cookies.get('myCookie');
        console.log('Cookie: ' + cook); //this doesn't work.shows undefined
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log('ERROR');
    });
```

}]);

Comment: Show your `console.log(document.cookie);`

Comment: It says: `(an empty string)`

Comment: So, you have not any client side cookie setted.

Comment: But a cookie received from `authURL` can be seen in Firebug.
How could it be resolved?

Comment: May be it is `httponly` cookie, not accessible by js.

Comment: Do you think there is some way out?

Comment: Where you set this cookie? serverside? What PL was used?

Comment: See `httponly` parameter [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) (for php)

Comment: I am not authorized to amend Serverside...

Comment: So, you not authorized to operate with this cookie :)